# Is it possible to trigger codebuild from aws cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to write a template that configures the whole ecs fargate server and its code pipeline.

There is no problem in all other configurations, but the image is empty because it is right after creating the ecr in cloudformation, and the create ecs service refers to the empty image and the process does not end.

So I want to push the server image to ecr with code build and then ecs service create to work, but I don't know how.

Could it be possible to trigger code build or code pipeline inside cloudformation?
If not, is there any way to do docker build & push?

Comment: You can use codebuild to trigger cloudformation stack? Why you try to do other way around?

Comment: The gist of the question is whether it is possible to process a single task of pushing an image to ecr as a resource by directly triggering the codebuild created within cloudformation, rather than triggering cloudformation in codebuild.

Comment: Yes, its possible through a custom resource.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to trigger the Fargate deployment after pushing the image rather than when the CloudFormation template is run.

[image]

The trick is to set the `DesiredCount` property of `AWS::ECS::Service` to zero:

```
Service:
  Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  Properties:
    Cluster: !Ref Cluster
    DesiredCount: 0
    LaunchType: FARGATE
    NetworkConfiguration:
      AwsvpcConfiguration:
        SecurityGroups:
          - !Ref SecG
        Subnets: !Ref Subs
    ServiceName: !Select [4, !Split ['-', !Select [2, !Split ['/', !Ref AWS::StackId]]]]
    TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
```

That said, you can also choose to create a repo with an initial commit that will trigger the build as soon as the template is done executing. This requires you to upload the zipped source code to an S3 bucket and configure the CodeCommit repository like so:

```
Repo:
  Type: AWS::CodeCommit::Repository
  Properties:
    Code:
      BranchName: main
      S3:
        Bucket: some-bucket
        Key: code.zip
    RepositoryName: !Select [4, !Split ['-', !Select [2, !Split ['/', !Ref AWS::StackId]]]]
    RepositoryDescription: Repository
    Triggers:
      - Name: Trigger
        CustomData: The Code Repository
        DestinationArn: !Ref Topic
        Branches:
          - main
        Events: [all]
```

Note that the `some-bucket` S3 bucket needs to contain the zipped `.Dockerfile` and any source code without any .git directory included.

You can see my implementation of this system and the rest of the stack below:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: CloudFormation Stack to Trigger CodeBuild via CodePipeline

Parameters:
  SecG:
    Description: Single security group
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
  Subs:
    Description: Comma separated subnet IDs
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
  ImagesFile:
    Type: String
    Default: images.json

Resources:
  ArtifactBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      Tags:
        - Key: UseWithCodeDeploy
          Value: true

  CodeBuildServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Path: /
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: codebuild.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub 'ssm-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::StackName}'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
                -
                  Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                      - ssm:GetParameters
                      - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
                  Resource: '*'
        - PolicyName: !Sub 'logs-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::StackName}'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
                -
                  Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                      - logs:CreateLogGroup
                      - logs:CreateLogStream
                      - logs:PutLogEvents
                  Resource: '*'
        - PolicyName: !Sub 'ecr-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::StackName}'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
                -
                  Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                      - ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
                      - ecr:CompleteLayerUpload
                      - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
                      - ecr:InitiateLayerUpload
                      - ecr:PutImage
                      - ecr:UploadLayerPart
                      - lightsail:*
                  Resource: '*'
        - PolicyName: !Sub bkt-${ArtifactBucket}-${AWS::Region}
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
                -
                  Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                      - s3:ListBucket
                      - s3:GetBucketLocation
                      - s3:ListBucketVersions
                      - s3:GetBucketVersioning
                  Resource: 
                      - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactBucket}
                      - arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket
        - PolicyName: !Sub obj-${ArtifactBucket}-${AWS::Region}
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
                -
                  Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                      - s3:GetObject
                      - s3:PutObject
                      - s3:GetObjectAcl
                      - s3:PutObjectAcl
                      - s3:GetObjectTagging
                      - s3:PutObjectTagging
                      - s3:GetObjectVersion
                      - s3:GetObjectVersionAcl
                      - s3:PutObjectVersionAcl
                  Resource: 
                      - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactBucket}/*
                      - arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/*
  CodeDeployServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Sid: '1'
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - codedeploy.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
                - codedeploy.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeDeployRoleForECS
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSCodeDeployRole
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSCodeDeployRoleForLambda
  CodeDeployRolePolicies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: !Sub 'CDPolicy-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::StackName}'
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Resource:
              - '*'
            Action:
              - ec2:Describe*
          - Effect: Allow
            Resource:
              - '*'
            Action:
              - autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction
              - autoscaling:DeleteLifecycleHook
              - autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks
              - autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups
              - autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook
              - autoscaling:RecordLifecycleActionHeartbeat
      Roles:
        - !Ref CodeDeployServiceRole
  CodePipelineServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Path: /
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: codepipeline.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub 'root-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::StackName}'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Resource:
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactBucket}/*'
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactBucket}'
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:GetObjectVersion
                  - s3:GetBucketAcl
                  - s3:GetBucketLocation
              - Resource: "*"
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ecs:*
              - Resource: "*"
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - iam:PassRole
                Condition:
                  StringLike:
                    iam:PassedToService:
                      - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
              - Resource: !GetAtt Build.Arn
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - codebuild:BatchGetBuilds
                  - codebuild:StartBuild
                  - codebuild:BatchGetBuildBatches
                  - codebuild:StartBuildBatch
              - Resource: !GetAtt Repo.Arn
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - codecommit:CancelUploadArchive
                  - codecommit:GetBranch
                  - codecommit:GetCommit
                  - codecommit:GetRepository
                  - codecommit:GetUploadArchiveStatus
                  - codecommit:UploadArchive

  AmazonCloudWatchEventRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          -
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - events.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: cwe-pipeline-execution
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: Allow
                Action: codepipeline:StartPipelineExecution
                Resource: !Sub arn:aws:codepipeline:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${Pipeline}
  AmazonCloudWatchEventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.codecommit
        detail-type:
          - CodeCommit Repository State Change
        resources:
          - !GetAtt Repo.Arn
        detail:
          event:
            - referenceCreated
            - referenceUpdated
          referenceType:
            - branch
          referenceName:
            - main
      Targets:
        -
          Arn: !Sub arn:aws:codepipeline:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${Pipeline}
          RoleArn: !GetAtt AmazonCloudWatchEventRole.Arn
          Id: codepipeline-Pipeline

  Topic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      Subscription:
        - Endpoint: user@example.com
          Protocol: email
  TopicPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
    Properties: 
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - 
            Sid: AllowPublish
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - 'codestar-notifications.amazonaws.com'
            Action:
              - 'SNS:Publish'
            Resource:
              - !Ref Topic
      Topics: 
        - !Ref Topic
  Repo:
    Type: AWS::CodeCommit::Repository
    Properties:
      Code:
        BranchName: main
        S3:
          Bucket: some-bucket
          Key: code.zip
      RepositoryName: !Select [4, !Split ['-', !Select [2, !Split ['/', !Ref AWS::StackId]]]]
      RepositoryDescription: Repository
      Triggers:
        - Name: Trigger
          CustomData: The Code Repository
          DestinationArn: !Ref Topic
          Branches:
            - main
          Events: [all]
  RepoUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
      Path: '/'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeCommitPowerUser
  RepoUserKey:
    Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties:
      UserName:
        !Ref RepoUser

  Registry: 
    Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
    Properties: 
      RepositoryName: !Select [4, !Split ['-', !Select [2, !Split ['/', !Ref AWS::StackId]]]]
      RepositoryPolicyText: 
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: AllowPushPull
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:  
                - !GetAtt CodeDeployServiceRole.Arn
            Action:
              - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
              - ecr:BatchGetImage
              - ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
              - ecr:PutImage
              - ecr:InitiateLayerUpload
              - ecr:UploadLayerPart
              - ecr:CompleteLayerUpload
  Build:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        BuildSpec: !Sub |
          version: 0.2
          phases:
            pre_build:
              commands:
                - echo "[`date`] PRE_BUILD"
                - echo "Logging in to Amazon ECR..."
                - aws ecr get-login-password --region $REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ACCOUNT.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com
                - IMAGE_URI="$ACCOUNT.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com/$REPO:$TAG"
            build:
              commands:
                - echo "[`date`] BUILD"
                - echo "Building Docker Image..."    
                - docker build -t $REPO:$TAG .
                - docker tag $REPO:$TAG $IMAGE_URI
            post_build:
              commands:
                - echo "[`date`] POST_BUILD"
                - echo "Pushing Docker Image..."
                - docker push $IMAGE_URI
                - echo Writing image definitions file...
                - printf '[{"name":"svc","imageUri":"%s"}]' $IMAGE_URI > $FILE
          artifacts:
              files: $FILE
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: aws/codebuild/standard:6.0
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        EnvironmentVariables:
          - Name: REGION
            Type: PLAINTEXT
            Value: !Ref AWS::Region
          - Name: ACCOUNT
            Type: PLAINTEXT
            Value: !Ref AWS::AccountId
          - Name: TAG
            Type: PLAINTEXT
            Value: latest
          - Name: REPO
            Type: PLAINTEXT
            Value: !Ref Registry
          - Name: FILE
            Type: PLAINTEXT
            Value: !Ref ImagesFile
        PrivilegedMode: true
      Name: !Ref AWS::StackName
      ServiceRole: !GetAtt CodeBuildServiceRole.Arn
  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineServiceRole.Arn
      ArtifactStore:
        Type: S3
        Location: !Ref ArtifactBucket
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: Site
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Version: '1'
                Provider: CodeCommit
              Configuration:
                RepositoryName: !GetAtt Repo.Name
                BranchName: main
                PollForSourceChanges: 'false'
              InputArtifacts: []
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceArtifact
              RunOrder: 1
        - Name: Build
          Actions:
            - Name: Docker
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Version: '1'
                Provider: CodeBuild
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref Build
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceArtifact
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildArtifact
              RunOrder: 1
        - Name: Deploy
          Actions:
            - Name: Fargate
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Version: '1'
                Provider: ECS
              Configuration:
                ClusterName: !Ref Cluster
                FileName: !Ref ImagesFile
                ServiceName: !GetAtt Service.Name
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildArtifact
              RunOrder: 1

  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Select [4, !Split ['-', !Select [2, !Split ['/', !Ref AWS::StackId]]]]
  FargateTaskExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
  TaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - 
          Name: svc
          Image: !Sub ${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${Registry}:latest
          PortMappings: 
            - ContainerPort: 8080
      Cpu: 256
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref FargateTaskExecutionRole
      Memory: 512
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      RuntimePlatform:
        CpuArchitecture: ARM64
        OperatingSystemFamily: LINUX
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole  
  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      DesiredCount: 0
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref SecG
          Subnets: !Ref Subs
      ServiceName: !Select [4, !Split ['-', !Select [2, !Split ['/', !Ref AWS::StackId]]]]
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition

Outputs:
  ArtifactBucketName:
    Description: ArtifactBucket S3 Bucket Name
    Value: !Ref ArtifactBucket
  ArtifactBucketSecureUrl:
    Description: ArtifactBucket S3 Bucket Domain Name
    Value: !Sub 'https://${ArtifactBucket.DomainName}'

  ClusterName:
    Value: !Ref Cluster
  ServiceName:
    Value: !GetAtt Service.Name

  RepoUserAccessKey:
    Description: S3 User Access Key
    Value: !Ref RepoUserKey
  RepoUserSecretKey:
    Description: S3 User Secret Key
    Value: !GetAtt RepoUserKey.SecretAccessKey

  BuildArn:
    Description: CodeBuild URL
    Value: !GetAtt Build.Arn
  RepoArn:
    Description: CodeCommit Repository ARN
    Value: !GetAtt Repo.Arn
  RepoName:
    Description: CodeCommit Repository NAme
    Value: !GetAtt Repo.Name
  RepoCloneUrlHttp:
    Description: CodeCommit HTTP Clone URL
    Value: !GetAtt Repo.CloneUrlHttp
  RepoCloneUrlSsh:
    Description: CodeCommit SSH Clone URL
    Value: !GetAtt Repo.CloneUrlSsh
  PipelineUrl:
    Description: CodePipeline URL
    Value: !Sub https://console.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/home?region=${AWS::Region}#/view/${Pipeline}
  RegistryUri:
    Description: ECR Repository URI
    Value: !GetAtt Registry.RepositoryUri
  TopicArn:
    Description: CodeCommit Notification SNS Topic ARN
    Value: !Ref Topic
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done, I used it before to perform jobs like a database restore as part of stack creation (don't ask). What you need:

1. A custom resource lambda which kicks off the codebuild job. It will receive the codebuild project to start via a property passed to it in the cloudformation resource definition (assuming that the codebuild is determined at deploy time; else feel free to make the lambda know about which codebuild to run in whatever way makes the most sense to you).
2. The endpoint to call when the custom resource is complete. A custom resource will stay in `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` state until the endpoint is called. It's been a while since I've used custom resources so don't remember where it comes from but I think it's found in the event that the custom resource lambda is invoked with.
3. Your codebuild job needs that endpoint and needs to be able to send a (`GET` or `POST`?) request to it, on both success and failure cases (you pass different params signifying success or failure).

So the overall sequence of steps is:

1. Define/reference the custom resource in your template, passing in whatever properties the lambda needs.
2. Deploy stack, custom resource lambda is invoked.
3. The custom resource status goes into `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`
4. Lambda kicks off codebuild, passing in custom resource endpoint as a param or env var, and returns.
5. Codebuild starts doing its work.
6. Until the endpoint is invoked, the custom resource will remain as `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`, and the stack create/update process will wait for it, even if it takes hours.
7. When codebuild has finished its work, it uses curl or similar to invoke that endpoint to signal it's complete.
8. Custom resource status goes to `CREATE_COMPLETE` (assuming you've invoked the endpoint with params saying it was successful).
9. Stack creation completes (or moves on to any resources that were dependent on the custom resource).